# laravel form model binding - date formatting

Tags: forms, binding, laravel, model, laravel-4

I have Laravel.  I have a form.  I have a MySQL database.  There are some dates in it.  When I bind the model and the form, the form is dutifully populated with raw MySQL dates.  This is obviously not what I need.

My question is: How do I get a model bound form to display dates in a more readable way?!?  There is not chance to intercept and format the data.  Or maybe for a more general solution, is there any way to do some proessing on any data between the model and the form, before the user sees it?

Am I thinking of this all wrong?  A billion thanks!

Comment: I don't have a lot of time so I can't give a complete answer, but you should check the docs here... http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#accessors-and-mutators   You can use the mutators to automatically give you a date format you want.

Comment: maybe a model presenter can help: http://culttt.com/2014/03/03/model-presenters-laravel-4/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may add an [accessor](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#accessors-and-mutators) method in your model like this:

```
public function getCreatedAtAttribute($date)
{
    $date = new \Carbon\Carbon($date);
    // Now modify and return the date
}
```

This will be called for `created_at`. Also check [date-mutators](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#date-mutators) if you need to override defaults. Check [Carbon Docs](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/).

Comment: can I modify this to access another field? 

ie: public function getMyOtherDateFieldAttribute($date){...

Comment: Yeah, you just name the function after whichever column you want to modify.  Just be sure to use camel case on the function name.

Comment: whats the fucntion name when the data field name is start_dt. Such as public function getStart_dtAttribute($date) {}. And why its compulsion to use carbon.

Comment: It should be `getStartDtAttribute` @webtuts4u :-)

Comment: Hey @"Trass Vasston", Accessor will always format the date and it could be a headache when you don't want to format it each and every case it retrieves )! So, I recommend @ollieread 's answer rather using an accessor.

Answer (score 2):

You can format the date in the form using the `format()` method.

If you're using it in a form element:

```
{{ Form::text('name', $model->created_at->format('d/m/Y H:i')) }}
```

If you're displaying it as plain text:

```
{{ $model->created_at->format('d/m/Y H:i') }}
```

If you would like the user to be able to modify the date in a nice way, you could use three different select fields. Here's an excerpt from a project I worked on that allows the user to change the date of birth:

```
<div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('date_of_birth') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
    {{ Form::label('date_of_birth', 'Date of Birth', ['class' => 'control-label']) }}
    <div class="form-inline">
        {{ Form::selectRange('date_of_birth[day]', 1, 31, null, ['class' => 'form-control']) }}
        {{ Form::selectMonth('date_of_birth[month]', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) }}
        {{ Form::selectYear('date_of_birth[year]', date('Y') - 3, date('Y') - 16, null, ['class' => 'form-control']) }}
    </div>
    {{ $errors->first('date_of_birth', '<span class="help-block">:message</span>') }}
</div>
```

This is contained within a form that has the model bound to it.

**Side Note**

The alternative answer posted in here actually overrides the default way that laravel handles dates, and unless you actually return a carbon object, you'll never have the luxury of using the `format` method, or any of the other handy things that carbon has.

If you have other columns that contain dates, add them to the data mutators list:

```
public function getDates()
{
    return ['created_at', 'updated_at', 'date_of_birth', 'some_date_column'];
}
```

This will now make it so that each of those is an instance of `Carbon` allowing you to format as you please, whenever you please and easily modify, duplicate and a whole host of other things. For more information regarding this, see: http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#date-mutators

Comment: `$date = new \Carbon\Carbon($date);` will produce a `Carbon` object, `$date` will become a `Carbon` object because of `new \Carbon\Carbon($date)`. In my answer I've mentioned `// Now modify and return the date`.

Comment: @WereWolf-TheAlpha Yeah, but if you return the `Carbon` object, then it ultimately has no real benefit over just using `format()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can format all fields retrieved from the database with creating an *Accessor* in your model. For example if your database field is `created_at` use `getCreatedAtAttribute`.

```
public function getCreatedAtAttribute($date)
{
    return Carbon::($date)->format('d/m/Y');
}
```